# Why is there a revision history?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list

I was just wondering why the revision history is important besides the facts that it allows users to see how a question has changed and have edit accountability.

I completely agree with having a revision history but I'm just curious if it helps solve other problems that I'm unaware of.

Comment: You have the two main points. Don't you think those are important?

Comment: I was thinking there might be other reasons for which I'm unaware. I'm very much for a revision history but I wanted a complete picture of what all it does from a usability standpoint.

Comment: To add a third, it's extremely useful data to have lying around for analysis. If you don't keep the history you're destroying a lot of information on how helpful the editing system/individual editors are or, for instance, on whether title A will get your question closed quicker - if the title has been removed then the data's gone. It's not a reason for showing the revision history but it's definitely a rationale for having one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The revision history has many uses

- Make sense of changes to a post; for example why an answer or comment refers to something that no longer exists
- Give credit to editors
- If a post is made worse by an edit (or worse still is vandalised) then it can be rolled back to its last good version
- Encourage people not to include a revision history within the post itself (for example <strike>strike</strike> or "Edit:...") which distracts from the actual information in the post

Answer (score 5):

One major advantage of having a revision history is to allow reversals or "rollbacks" of invalid edits, either the original poster's (which happens more often then I'd like) or more commonly someone else's. It's not uncommon for a revision to change a question's nature to such a degree as to completely invalidate all present answers.

Without the revision history, fixing this would be impossible.